# Soft restart on Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm using the `PassengerPreStart` and `touch tmp/restart.txt` to restart my app. Still, it is very slow (10s) to finish the restart process. This make a poor users experience on restart.

It would be nice if servers were not shutdown immediately, and some resquests were still served using the old servers, until the new servers finish their load and are ready to take requests quickly.

Is that possible with Passenger? Is it possible with another Rails webserver? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of their [enterprise package](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/enterprise).

[Documentation for rolling restarts in Apache](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRollingRestarts)

Unicorn also supports rolling restarts. [Same question, but for Unicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995296/how-to-do-rolling-restart-with-unicorn)

Comment: Thanks @woahdae, I'll have to migrate to unicorn for this feature